# How to add an "add" button that sticks at the end of a listbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, stackpanel

I've been looking almost all night for a way to have this nice "add" button at the bottom of a ListBox. The thing is I want it to stick at the bottom of the listbox, and then once the bottom of the border is reached, I want the listbox to become scrollable so that the add button doesn't get out of the border. Right now I do it with two rows but I would like the button to be precisely at the bottom of the list, while still not going out of the border when the list grows bigger. Any Idea ? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Why isn't it just a button outside the listbox and  underneath it?

Comment: `<Border> <StackPanel> <ListBox /> <Button /> </StackPanel> </Border>`

Comment: @Andy  the thing is when the listbox grows bigger the button goes out of the border. I would like it to stop nicely at the bottom of the border and then the listbox would become scollable. But thanks anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so I finally found my way through this simple yet annoying thing :
The trick was to use a DockPanel and put the button at the bottom, while having all the controls vertically aligned to the top.

```
<DockPanel Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Width="20" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: No point in downvoting without explaining why.. What's wrong with this answer ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: The button still sticks to the bottom (which DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" is supposed to do)